# Prices display incorrectly in the source code

Tags: magento-1.7

I am wondering if i could get some advice for a bug fix in regards to our Magento system.

The issue is as follows:

Our website (http://www.optimusprotein.co.uk) by default displays all of item sale prices to two decimal places (e.g 0.49 for 49 pence) however, once a transaction is complete, the prices track in the back end of the source code as 4 decimal places (e.g 0.4900) This is not causing us any major issues, however we have just become a member of an affiliate program and they are requesting that the prices need to track consistently to 2 decimal places accordingly.

I have tried everything in regards to downloading extensions etc, but nothing seems to work so I believe the problem must lie deep in the source code.

Any advice you can give me would be great.

Comment: Where exactly are the prices showing up with 4 decimal places in the admin section? I can tell you that the reason why there are 4 decimal places is because the datatype in the database is DECIMAL(12,4). See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html) for more info.

Comment: My apologies, I overlook that you were seeing the prices in the code. In that case, you simply need to format the value before it is given over to whatever program. You could perhaps do something like this `$finalprice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($rawprice)`

Answer (score 1):

In Magento all database fields which handle price information are of DECIMAL(12,4), ie have room for 4 decimal places. By default Magento will round prices to 2 decimal places - see Mage_Core_Model_Store

```
/**
 * Round price
 *
 * @param mixed $price
 * @return double
 */
public function roundPrice($price)
{
    return round($price, 2);
}
```

It sounds like you will only need to adjust the format of the price when passing the information to the affiliate scheme:

```
echo sprintf("%9.2f", '0.4900'); //0.49
```